# How to add Google Tag Manager to Prestashop v. 1.7.7

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I added the script code to the head in layout-both-columns.tpl with {literal} tags and the noscript right under the body id="{$page.page_name}" class="{$page.body_classes|classnames}"> without {literal} tags

Google tag manager just doesn't seem to read it.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: If you open your website source code, do you see the code you added or not? :)